# Что означает оператор "стрелочка" в контексте объявления свойства

Tags: c#, .net, классы, операторы

Столкнулся с непонятным фрагментом кода

```
public EndPoint LocalEndPoint => _remote.LocalEndPoint;
```

Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь, подскажите пожалуйста куда копать что бы понять что это такое?

В microsoft.docs => лямбда оператор, однако впервые вижу что бы его так использовали.

Comment: expression bodied property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это не лямбда, это [появившаяся в C# 6](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied--members) укороченная запись для вычисляемого свойства

```
public EndPoint LocalEndPoint { get { return _remote.LocalEndPoint; } }
```

Comment: @Андрей вы пропустили важную частицу когда читали ответ

Comment: @PavelMayorov, согласен, косячу )

Comment: @Андрей зря вы свой ответ удалили, это ж не полный дубль. Может, кому-нибудь он будет понятнее?

Answer (score 3):

Это свойство, сжатое до выражения.

> Начиная с версии C# 6, свойство, допускающее только чтение можно
>   объявлять более кратко как *свойство, сжатое до выражения*
>   (expression-bodied property). Все фигурные скобки, а также ключевые
>   слова `get` и `return` заменяются комбинацией `=>`